# Term for bed sheet that embraces and partially encapsulates the mattress

Tags: word-request

I went to IKEA and got me a new sheet. It's awesome on the bed because instead of being "sheety", it's got those rubber parts so one doesn't **fold** it under the mattress to keep it in place but rather **skewers** it or maybe **embraces** it onto it.

1. What's that kind of sheet called?
2. What's the traditional, foldy, kind called?
3. What's the right verb to describe the thing you do with the new kind of sheet?

Comment: "[Skewering](https://www.google.com/search?q=skewer&tbm=isch)" does not seem like something a bedsheet can do.

Comment: Did you mean "secures it" instead of "skewers it"?

Comment: As a side-note, "I went and got me a ..." is marked and only good for some dialects of English.  The more standard way to say it would be "I went to IKEA and got a new sheet." or "I went to IKEA and got myself a new sheet."

Comment: +1 for the (unintended?) pun on "sheety".

Comment: @Jasper If one considers the whole bed as a stick (very short and quite think, that is) and the sheet as a baggy film, then - using a lot of imagination - one could view it as a commenced skewering process that hasn't perforated the fabric yet. Having said that, it was a linguistic hack in lack of better verb. Feel free to suggest one more adequate in this situation, hehe. And I didn't mean *secure*, rather *embrace*. I looked up the Swedish word for it and this is what I got. We use that verb both for putting stuff on a stick and for e.g. a condom. We Swedes are weird...   :)

Comment: @Gossar Correct remark as for fully proper English. I used the expression to create a humorous contrast between *got me sth*, which might be perceived as slang and the sophistication of purchasing fancy sheets. C.f. *ya'll ain't no gonna be reimbursed by the contemporary legislature*. If not intended, it's as weird as a medieval castle with ceiling. But I got me some humor so I intended the contrast indeed, I did.  :)

Comment: @MarchHo Yessss... Unintended, entirely unintended... (pronounced exaggeratedly slowly and ominously emphasizing *entirely*) Just like when one types *what the duck is that* (typo intended)...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Fitted** is the word you are looking for, a **fitted** sheet is the sheet above the mattress that has extra fabric to **extend around** the mattress and an **elasticized** outer edges to *fit* around the mattress holding it in place.

The other sheet is a **flat** sheet referred to as a **standard** bed sheet or **drop** sheet or **top** sheet.

When you are putting **fresh linens** on a bed, you are **making up** a bed.
The opposite is to **strip** *(down)* a bed.

The **total effect** of putting a bed together (sheets, pillows, covers) is called [**dressing a bed**](http://www.frontgate.com/inspiredliving/how-to-dress-up-your-bed-creating-a-designer-look-at-home/)

When you are tidying up a bed after sleeping in it, you are **making** a bed.
The common command by parents

> **Go make your bed!**

Before going to sleep, some hotels will **turn down** your bed by **folding back the covers** and (if you're lucky) leaving a **chocolate** on the **fluffed** pillows.

If you are in a mischievous mood, you can [**short sheet**](http://www.wikihow.com/Short-Sheet-a-Bed) a bed; a common prank played on newlyweds.

We spend about a third of our life on top of a **fitted sheet** *(usually)*, this intimate and **fated** relationship has lead to the phrase

> [**You've made your bed, now lie in it**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/you-ve-made-your-bed--now-lie-in-it)

since there's no escaping it.

Comment: In my dialect there is actually a distinction between "making the bed" and "making up the bed". I "make the bed" after I get up in the morning by smoothing out the sheets and pulling up the coverlet. I "make up the bed" on laundry day when I put fresh clean sheets on the bed. I don't know how common that distinction is. The opposite of making up the bed is stripping the sheets. The opposite of making the bed is turning down the bed.

Comment: What dialect is that?

Comment: Flat sheets are also known as *drop* sheets.

Comment: @ColleenV Totally unrelated to English - I'd like you to consider never *making your bed*. Apparently, when you put the covers on, the small, disgusting [bed mites](https://www.google.se/search?q=mite+bed&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dQurVvfjJIW5ygPH066oDg) have a party. By letting in the cold, dry air, you kill them off. (Warning for unpleasant pictures - don't click when eating or of sensitive.)

Comment: Did you mean to say *...and an elastic to fit...* using *elastic* as a noun? I like it better than *rubber thingy*. Just making sure it's a canonical term.

Comment: @ColleenV +1 Have incorporated your comments along with (at)Esoteric into the answer

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yup; "elastic" can be used as a noun. Its common when discussing fabric. In some places, it's also used to refer to the office supply item otherwise known as a "rubber band".

Comment: **Elastic bands** invented 170 years ago, about now (patent awarded Mar 17, 1845). Royal Mail uses 2 million **red** ones **every day**

Comment: @KonradViltersten I think you mean dust mites - bed mites might be confused with bed bugs which are a different creature. Regardless, if you clean your linens regularly in hot water you can still make your bed. http://www.webmd.com/allergies/guide/dust-allergies http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/insects/find/bed-bugs-in-residences/

Answer (score 13):

From [Wikipedia...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_sheet)

> *a **fitted sheet** has its four corners, and sometimes two or four sides, fitted with elastic, to be used only as a bottom sheet.*

You still [***make** the bed*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/make-the-bed) regardless of whether it has a fitted sheet. But if it *does*, people often call the other one<sup>1</sup> a ***top** sheet* to distinguish it from the elasticated one (a fitted sheet doesn't work on top).

---

<sup>1</sup> If indeed there *is* another sheet - increasingly less likely as we move from top sheets under "itchy" blankets to removable covers on duvets.

Comment: Agreed, in common daily use I hear and use _top sheet_ and _bottom sheet_.  In a more commercial, technical, or formal setting I would use _flat sheet_ and _fitted sheet_ respectively.

Comment: Hmm... Let alone that we Swedes are weird but *top sheet* and *bottom sheet*? The sheet I'm talking about tucks in the mattress and I sleep directly on it. The only thing that's on top of that is the cover... So vertical intersection would be: the cover/blanket, my butt, the sheet, the mattress, some air, the floor... How do others do...?

Comment: @KonradViltersten:  We swedes normally use only a duvet cover and no top sheet. In other countries it seems common to use flat sheets on top as well - between yourself and the blanket (or whatever you have over yourself for warmth).

Comment: @EmilStyrke Oh, now I see... Last week, it'd be a great idea because we had negative 18 degrees in Stockholm and the heating in my building kind of died... I had to go to CleasOhlsson and get one of those ugly, blue [heat fans](http://images.clasohlson.com/medias/sys_master/9035180965918.jpg) or whatever it's called...

Comment: Since the top sheet is only a single layer I doubt it adds much warmth, but an extra blanket is useful in those cases of course. :) I think the blue thing would be called a "space heater", by the way.

Comment: @KonradViltersten "fan heater" (BrEng).

Comment: @AE I see where you're coming from. However, that's not precisely what I referred to. The item I showed was a fan heater, indeed, but the reference was not to any such fan heater but this specific type that's used at construction sites etc. It's way too ugly and "outdoory" to be used in ones house. It's moist resistant and heavy duty, consuming the energy very wastefully but getting the heat up in no time. We call it *construction (site) fan (heater)* and it's different from just a *fan heater*. Is it the same term in English anyway?

Comment: @Konrad: As Emil says, those big fans are usually called *[industrial] **space** heaters*.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to have to make a trip to IKEA because it sounds like you are not describing a traditional fitted sheet.  It sounds like you are describing a modified standard sheet where the corners have rubber (for grip) pockets sewn in such that the corners of the mattress fit into the rubber pockets of the sheet which holds the sheet firmly attached to the mattress like a fitted sheet. But this kind of sheet seems like it would be much easier to fold than a traditional fitted sheet.  I would still say, "making the bed" with this kind of sheet, but to describe the specific action of hooking the sheet pocket around the mattress corner I would probably say I was, "buttoning" the sheet down, or "dressing" the mattress up.

Comment: No need to go to IKEA. The reason for my question is that while I love fitted sheets **on the bed**, folding the suckers is a major PIA. So I was looking for a life hack on how to do that. For that, I needed a term to search for. Now I got one. And violá - [first hit on Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z5k9nWcuFc)! I'm so happy now!

Comment: @Konrad: I'm so happy too! I've always made a dog's dinner of folding my fitted sheets, but I never thought of looking for a Youtube guide. (I'm looking forward to laundry day now, to see if it works! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, until recently I had an even better system. Two sets of sheets. One on the bed being used. The other in the hamper waiting for laundry. Then... Along came a third one and the whole system collapsed, resulting in me looking for life hacks, which led to this question. I'm seriously considering disposing one of the sets and get back to my non-folding system altogether, hehe.

Comment: A viola is a musical instrument.  The word  you're looking for is voilà.  @KonradViltersten

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm aware. It appears that you're missing the accent above my "a". It does read *violá*. Perhaps the thingy is in the wrong direction but I seem not to have that character (humanly easily) accessible from my keyboard.

Comment: The problem is more the order of the O and the I.

Comment: I wouldn't have noticed if all you'd done was reverse the angle of the accent.

Answer (score 3):

The name "Fitted Sheet" has already been given.

I was going to suggest "evil sheet of difficult foldiness and doom", but since I see that issue has been dealt with, I'll suggest instead *contour sheet* as a relatively uncommon synonym used -- so far as I can tell -- mostly by marketers trying to make them sound fancier.

I am interested by your description of them as "fancy" sheets. Growing up in the UK, I found beds with fitted sheets to be frowned upon as "not as good".

I think, though, that this might be more a factor of the amount of extra work needed to provide crisp linen sheets carefully tucked into the corners of the bed. So upmarket hotels generally provide tucked-in apple-pie beds because it provides the impression of hand-cared service, but likely also because there's no elastic to go out on them if you wash them very hot, so they last longer, and are probably cheaper.

Comment: I might guess that the *evil sheets of difficult foldiness and doom* could be spared from frowning for the same reason why home-grind beans are considered the base for a better coffee than instant coffee powder. Or eating on a silver platter or exclusive china being base for a culinary excellence? One needs to invest more work, it's more costly, so the reptile brains tells us it's better?

Comment: Also, I learned that in many cases, the **less usual** something is in a region, the more exclusive and desirable it becomes. In US, people pay top dollar for a car with an automatic transmission. Why, for duck's sake, why?! (Quack-a-roonie intended.) In Sweden, it's actually the opposite. If we want an automatic, it can bump up the price by 15%. (And for the record, the only way for manual to be desirable should be on  a bike!)